# Searching key in Dart map if key is a list

Tags: dictionary, dart

I'm solving a problem which is on a website "exercism.io" of Dart.[Link to problem statement](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/61f5ad417b934da8b0f6acd1827e1e95)
I'm using map as a data structure and key data type is List.
The problem arises when I try to access the map, I'm confused how to search the list for that key.

I tried asking on different platforms like slacks but got no help. Also, I tried to search a similar problem but unfortunately since Dart is a new language there is not much out there.

```
int score(String str) {
  int score;
  //Map declaration and definition 
  Map<List<String>, int> scrabbleDat = {
    //list as a key and int as a value
    ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T']: 1,
    ['D', 'G']: 2,
    ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P']: 3,
    ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y']: 4,
    ['K']: 5,
    ['J', 'X']: 8,
    ['Q', 'Z']: 10
  };
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
    //Trying to access map based on the str parameter
    //Adding the value returned to score variable
    score += scrabbleDat[str[i]];
  }
  return score; // returning the score
}
```

The code is running flawlessly but the output obtained is null for any string.

Comment: This does no make sense.  You are passing in a String type, but your map key is a list of individual characters.  Why?

Comment: I want to get it's corresponding value if any of the characters is obtained in the map. The thing I'm confused is how to access the list when accessing the map to search the key which is on the list. 
Also, I'm confused as to why the program is running at all if the key data type is list and value I'm passing is a string?

Comment: This does work properly: `score += scrabbleDat[scrabbleDat.keys.firstWhere((list) => list.contains(str[i]))];`, tough IMO this is not a good way to organize the map structure. Also you need to initialize the `score` variable (to `0` most likely)

Comment: @Mattia Yes, I would love to initialize the `score` value to `0` but `score` was `null` by default.

Comment: @Mattia 
```$ pub run test

00:01 +0 -1: test/scrabble_score_test.dart: Scrabble score should return a
 score of 0 for empty input [E]

  Expected: <0>

    Actual: <null>

  
  package:test_api                   expect

  test/scrabble_score_test.dart 8:9  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>

  
00:01 +0 ~11 -1: Some tests failed.
```
Still I'm getting a null and I know it's a bad example of using map but was trying out something new. I will try using another method .

Comment: It works properly on dart pad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/72e759429a071a9057124b3bf9ab1984

Comment: @Mattia Wow you are amazing!. Thanks for the help, there was a minor problem from my end.

Comment: Using a `List` as a key negates the advantage of using a `Map` for your case; when doing a lookup, you iterate over the entire `Map`.  It would be better to invert it (`Map<int, List<String>> scrabbleDat = {1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'], ...}`).  At runtime, you then can do a one-time pass through `scrabbleDat` to create a `Map<String, int>` that maps *each* letter to its score.  Your `score` function then can do an efficient lookup for each letter.

Comment: Yes, Mattia's code will work, but it's about 1000x slower than necessary for what is basically a simple 26-element lookup table. Using a map at all is horribly wasteful of both memory and time, and testing for list containment compounds that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a map where multiple keys map to the same value.

Using lists of values as keys does not let you look up efficiently. You can search linearly through the keys, and then through the individual lists, until you find the key you are looking for, but you are not using the map as a *`Map`*.

I'd build the map so that it has each key mapped to its value directly:

```
Map<String, int> map = {};
void _addAll(List<String> keys, int value) { 
  for (var key in keys) map[key] = value;
}
_addAll(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'], 1);
_addAll(['D', 'G'], 2);
_addAll(['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'], 3);
_addAll(['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'], 4);
_addAll(['K'], 5);  // or just: map['K'] = 5;
_addAll(['J', 'X'], 8);
_addAll(['Q', 'Z'], 10);
```

It's not that much easier than simply writing the map literal:

```
var map = {
  'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'C': 3, 'D': 2, 'E': 1, 'F': 4, 'G': 2, 'H': 4,
  'I': 1, 'J': 8, 'K': 5, 'L': 1, 'M': 3, 'N': 1, 'O': 1, 'P': 3,
  'Q': 10, 'R': 1, 'S': 1, 'T': 1, 'U': 1, 'V': 4, 'W': 4, ,X': 8,
  'Y': 4, 'Z': 10
};
```

After this, your map is initialized, and you can look up each letter directly:

```
print(map['X']);  // prints 8.
```

Another option, since your keys have consequtive ASCII values, is to make an
index based table, and calculate the index from the letter's ASCII value:

```
//           A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q  R S T U V W X Y Z
var table = [1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10];
int lookup(String letter) => table[letter.codeUnitAt(0) - 0x41 /*A*/];
```

Comment: Dart keeps giving: Error: Expected an identifier errors in the _addAll function.

Comment: The `_addAll` function call must happen inside a function. Dart does not allow top-level function calls.